# Unexpected Token Syntax Error In If Statement With React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting a syntax error in when using React Hooks. Basically, I'm using an `If` statement inside `useEffect` and getting and Unexpected token error.

```
const [linkAnimation, setLinkAnimation] = useState();
const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    setLinkAnimation( 
      if(isHovered === true){  //getting unexpected token on this line
        console.log('true')
      }
    );
}, []);
```

Syntax seems straight forward, but looks like I'm missing something.

See [codepen](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/wvwGjVG)

Comment: the syntax is wrong. see [Expressions versus statements in JavaScript](https://2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html)

Comment: `setLinkAnimation` is a function, and you are passing a `if statement` as an argument to the function. Error is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setState function is expecting a value of some sort, but instead is just a function (console.log). If you wrap it in a fat arrow function with an implicit or explicit return, it works.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setLinkAnimation( () => {
      if(isHovered === true){
        console.log('true')
      }
    });
}, []);
```

Edit: Please note that this will still not set the state, but it will at least complete your `console.log`.

Answer (score 3):

The `if` statement is currently the parameter for your call to `setLinkAnimation`

I think you're actually trying to do something like this:

```
const [linkAnimation, setLinkAnimation] = useState();
const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
  if(isHovered === true){  //getting unexpected token on this line
    console.log('true')
    setLinkAnimation(true);
  }
}, []);
```